# Is it safe to use the Abandoned Shack for storage?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it safe to leave things in the abandoned shack chest and dresser after you join the dark brotherhood?

Answer (score 3):

I've tried storing items in the shack too; it has not disappeared until now, though I highly doubt it will remain there forever like it does for houses.

I read that the game engine is resetting stuff once in seven days (in Skyrim time), so if you're not revisiting the shack in seven days, the stuff would disappear.

It is safer to keep the items in the guild instead. Or more preferably, in your own house.

Comment: alright thanks i was confused because ingots and assorted jewelry and stuff was gone but the daedric artifacts i had were still there so i didnt know if it was possible to get robbed or something crazy was happening. house=bought lol